# How to pass argument got from ellipsis operator to other function?

Tags: c++, printf, ellipsis

```
void myPrintf(const char* format, ...) {
    // some code
    va_list vl;
    printf(format, vl);
}

int main() {
    myPrintf("%d\n", 78);
}
```

In this code I have tried to pass the argument from ellipsis to `printf`. It compiles but prints garbage instead of 78. What is the right way of doing it?

Comment: because `vl` is not initialzied

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
void myPrintf(const char *format, ...) {
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl, format);
    vprintf(format, vl);
    va_end(vl);
}
```

Please note the use of `vprintf` instead of `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. The first is that you don't initialize `vl`, use [`va_start`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_start) for that. Don't forget to use [`va_end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_end) afterwards.
2. The other problem is that `printf` doesn't take a `va_list` argument. Use [`vprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf) for that.

Comment: How to initalize vl I donth know the count of arguments. Should I count % signs in format

Comment: @Ashot See my updated answer, and follow the reference links.

Answer (score 0):

First Initialize `vl`

`va_start(vl,1);  //No. of arguments =1`

Then take the `int` from it

`printf(format, va_arg(vl,int));`