# How to pass ellipsis arguments to other function which use ellipsis?

Tags: c++, c

I have looked up this question: [How to pass argument got from ellipsis operator to other function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715895/how-to-pass-argument-got-from-ellipsis-operator-to-other-function)

But it can't be applied here:

```
void foo(const char *, ...); //call printf
void bar(const char *, ...); //call foo
```

I want something like this:

```
void bar(const char *format, ...){
  foo(format, ...);
}
```

I know I can use `vprintf` for `printf` but there's no similar `vfoo` for `foo`

How?

Comment: Look at `vfprintf()` et al — you pass a `va_list`.  There's a duplicate; I'm off to find it...

Comment: It looks like the real question here might be how to implement a `void vfoo(const char *, va_list args)`.

Comment: `printf` have `vprintf` but `foo` don't have `vfoo`

Comment: So I'm guessing you can't make a `vfoo` taking a `va_list`?

Comment: As the question to which I've made this a duplicate says, you need to create the `vfoo()`.  You will modify your existing `foo()` to call `vfoo()` as an internal implementation detail, but the vast majority of the code from `foo()` will transplant to `vfoo()` and what's left in `foo()` will be a tiny stub that translates from `...` to `va_list`.

Comment: See also some of the other questions in the 'related' list at the RHS of the page.  Sadly, the highest voted question [Passing variable number of arguments around](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205529/passing-variable-number-of-arguments-around) is a little shambolic in presentation, for all it has a lot of votes.

Comment: the solution to this problem in C and C++ is quite different.  Are you programming in C, C++ or the intersection of the two?

Comment: @Yakk please tell me what's the difference. Also, can I apply the solution from C to C++?

Comment: I asked a pretty clear questions about your problem.  You have not answered it.  If you answer it, I may have followup questions.  If you do not have an actual practical problem, or do not feel like answering my questions to find a possibly better solution, feel free to continue not answering my questions.

Comment: @Yakk you told me that the solution to C and C++ is quite different.
I'm a C++ programmer. I wonder if there's some solutions in C++ better than in C.

Comment: @DMaster, Likely variadic templates.

Comment: @DMaster sounds like an XY problem.  In C++ you wouldn't use `...` in the first place.